# While loop stack overflow

Tags: java, android, stack-overflow, do-while

I use this method, and i get the while loop stack overflow.
No error message or crash. I got this in my log cat:

```
05-18 20:17:16.528: W/InputEventReceiver(19831): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
```

When i put this code in my while boolean:

```
data.numberOfSameDateRows(selectedDay) != 0
```

the loop is fine.
But when i use it like below i got stack overflow.

```
if(data.numberOfSameDateRows(selectedDay) != 0)
                i=0;
            else
                i++;
```

Thank for helping :)

Here is my code:

```
DataBaseMain data = new DataBaseMain(this);
    data.open();

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("d-MMMM-yyyy");
    String dateWanted = getCorrectDate(removeSpinner);

    Date wantedDate = new Date();
    int i = 0;

    try {
        wantedDate = dateFormatter.parse(dateWanted);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Calendar myCal = new GregorianCalendar();
    myCal.setTime(wantedDate);
    Date newDate = myCal.getTime(); 
    String selectedDay = dateFormatter.format(newDate);

    if(dateWanted.equals("all") == false){  

    do{ 
    if(data.numberOfSameDateRows(selectedDay) != 0)
            i=0;
        else
            i++;

    myCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 7);     
    newDate = myCal.getTime();  
    selectedDay = dateFormatter.format(newDate);

    }
    while(i < 5);


public int numberOfSameDateRows(String date){

        int i = 0;
        String[] columns = new String[]{COLUMN_DATE};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, COLUMN_DATE + "= '" + date + "'", null, null, null, null);

    if(c.getCount() >= 1)
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            i++;
        }   

    return i;   
    }
```

Comment: if `if(data.numberOfSameDateRows(selectedDay) != 0)` is true, you never increment `i`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun i tried to remove `if(data.numberOfSameDateRows(selectedDay) != 0)`, leaving only `i++`.
And i still got it stack overflow

Comment: can you post the entire code>

Comment: you never close your cursore. c.close(); before return i; Also, inside numberOfSameDateRows, why do you need the for() since you are returning c.getCount();

Comment: I reright the code, completley the same and its working. Maybe it was eclipse bug. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an infinite loop. Thus never ending and causing a stack overflow.

```
do{ 
if(data.numberOfSameDateRows(selectedDay) != 0)
        i=0;
    else
        i++;

myCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 7);     
newDate = myCal.getTime();  
selectedDay = dateFormatter.format(newDate);

}
while(i < 5);
```

You have you while set to i < 5 but in the do statement you keep setting i = 0.

This will cause i to set to 0 every time then you will never reach to i=5 and you will be stuck in there consuming resources. Also the highest i will ever reach is 1.

I would recommend setting i = 0 prior to the do statement so it isn't within the loop.

Fix that and hopefully it will work.

Comment: I reright the code, completley the same and its working. Maybe it was eclipse bug. Thanks for helping